# What is this Highstocks UI element, and can it be controlled independently of the tooltip?

Tags: highcharts

The image below is a marked-up screenshot from an example of Highstocks API in [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/):

[image: Highstocks Example]

Unlike the Highcharts API, the Highstocks API provides (what appears to be) **two** tooltips instead of one.

...but *I'm not sure*.

I'm attempting to control the element circled in red, but cannot find anywhere in [Highstocks documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/) on what this element *truly* is. Overriding/hiding the tooltip appears to eliminate both the green and the red element, and for an API with an extraordinary level of control/customization, I fear this is just me missing some larger point.

1. Is the red element actually considered the tooltip? If it is, how do you configure/control it, independently from the green tooltip?
2. If the red element *isn't* the tooltip...then what is it?

**EDIT**

Here's a screenshot of the chart using:

```
tooltip: {
  split: true
}
```

[image: split = true]

...and here's that same chart with

```
tooltip: {
  split: false
}
```

[image]

As you can see in the second photo, setting the `tooltip`'s `split` property to `false` doesn't *really* control that unidentified element, as it simply moves to a different place in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch on the `split` parameter of the tooltip, then it's divided for two parts, namely the point and header. In the documentation, you can find both of the formatters here: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.headerFormat, https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.pointFormat .
Additionally, here is the example code of formatting the "element marked with red":

```
tooltip: {
  split: true,
  headerFormat: '<span>It is tooltip header - {point.key}</span>'
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/0eqmv7sw/

Answer (score 0):

It's a tooltip but with the default option `split : true` - [API Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.split)

With `split : false` you will see just the "default" tooltip

```
    tooltip:{
      enabled:true,
      split:false
    },
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/jvpo42r9/)

**Edit :**

If you are looking for the vertical line too it's `xAxis.crosshair` - [API Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.crosshair)